# How do i fix a non static method being called in Main?

Tags: java, static

I want to call a non static method in Main, but thats against coding rules, so now i cant do the things i want. How can i fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter infix expression: ");
        String userInput = input.next();
        System.out.println("Summary");
        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println("Infix: " + userInput);
        System.out.println("Postfix: " + infixToPostfix(userInput));
        System.out.println("Result: " + evalPostfix(infixToPostfix(userInput)));
    }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
non static method infixToPostfix(java.lang.string) cannot be refranced from a static context
```

and

```
non static method evalPostfix(java.lang.string) cannot be refranced from a static context
```

I need to use them here to get the correct answers printed.

Comment: Have the main in a separate class calling all functions from a function class

Comment: The quickest fix here would just be to make both of your helper methods `static`.

Comment: @JoshW. i tried that, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick fix:**

Make your `infixToPostfix(...)` and `evalPostfix(...)` methods static.

**More object-oriented fix:**

Your static main method should instantiate an instance of the class containing `infixToPostfix(...)` and `evalPostfix(...)` which could be the class containing the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); // make an instance

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter infix expression: ");
    String userInput = input.next();
    System.out.println("Summary");
    System.out.println("-------");
    System.out.println("Infix: " + userInput);
    System.out.println("Postfix: " + myClass.infixToPostfix(userInput)); // use your instance
    System.out.println("Result: " + myClass.evalPostfix(infixToPostfix(userInput))); // use your instance
}
```

Comment: The static fix worked for my program. Although the class fix looked cool, but will not work because my program isnt object orented. Thank you!

Comment: You are coding in Java, therefore your program is object oriented. Even if you only have one object - the one containing your main method.

Comment: Yeah, i giess you are right. I just meant, i am only working with one class, everything else is done in methods.

Comment: Well that is still not a convincing reason.  The object could be an instance of the class that defines the `main` method.  If you are writing in Java, you should be writing OO (and avoiding static) unless there is a compelling reason not to.  Even for small things.  It is only about 1 line of extra code to create a trivial instance of the current class so that you can invoke methods on it.